# How can I get xargs to do something with the input, then do another thing?

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, xargs

I'm in zsh.

I'd like to do something like:

`find . -iname *.md | xargs cat && echo "---" > all_slides_with_separators_in_between.md`

Of course this cats all the slides, then appends a single "---" at the end instead of after each slide.

Is there an xargs way of doing this? Can I replace `cat && echo "---"` with some inline function or `do` block?

---

Very strangely, when I create a file `cat---.sh` with the contents

```
cat $1
echo ---
```

and run

`find . -iname *.md | xargs ./cat---.sh`

it only executes for the first result of find.
Replace cat---.sh with cat and it runs on both files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate. I'll see if I can find a suitable old question; this one should then be closed.

Comment: BTW, see the "complex actions" section of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: BTW, even though zsh *often* lets you be lazy about quoting, calling `find` isn't one of those times. You want `-iname '*.md'`, not `-iname *.md`, or else the glob will be expanded to refer to filenames in the current directory (should any matches exist) before `find` is invoked.

Comment: Your script only processes the first argument. You'll need to loop over its arguments, or call it with `xargs -n1` (or straight with `find -exec` as in @CharkesDuffy's answer).

Comment: Yup. If the script were written as `for arg; do cat "$arg" && echo ---; done`, that would work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.SE

Comment: @Freiheit, do you concede that the `shell`, `bash`, `zsh`, &c. tags have any place on StackOverflow? If they do, what distinguishes questions which belong here and those that belong on unix.SE?

Comment: @Freiheit, ...to be clear, I consider questions clearly relevant only to interactive command-line use off-topic, but don't believe that this is onesuch; this could could easily be something placed in a makefile or build script, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use `xargs` at all here. Following is a properly paranoid approach (robust against files with spaces, files with newlines, files with literal backslashes in their names, etc):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  printf '---\n'
  cat -- "$filename"
done < <(find . -iname '*.md' -print0) >all_slides_with_separators.md
```

---

However -- you don't even need that either: `find` can do all the work itself, both printing the separator *and* calling `cat`!

```
find . -iname '*.md' -printf '---\n' -exec cat -- '{}' ';' >all_slides_with_separators.md
```

Comment: My version of find (BSD on OSX) doesn't have a `-printf` so I needed `-exec echo '---' ';'` instead. But otherwise it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A common usage pattern is `xargs sh -c 'command; another' _` where the entire shell script in the quotes will have access to the command-line arguments. The  underscore is because the first  argument to `sh -c` will be assigned to `$0` (where you'd often see e.g. `-sh` in a `ps` listing).

```
find . -iname '*.md' |
xargs sh -c 'for x; do
  cat "$x" && echo "---"
done' _ > all_slides_with_separators_in_between.md
```

As noted in the comments, you should probably investigate `find -print0` and the corresponding `xargs -0` option in GNU `find` (and  maybe install it if you don't have it).

Comment: Needs quotes around the wildcard, or this will fail badly with any .md files in the current directory.

Comment: Also, probably worth suggesting use of `find -print0` / `xargs -0` to avoid unpleasant surprises with literal newlines in file or directory names.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, but **it can be insecure in some cases** (see comments):

`find . -iname '*.md' | xargs -I % sh -c '{ cat %; echo "----"; }' > output.txt`

Comment: Much less secure than either preexisting answer: This evaluates expansions inside filename literals, by passing the files found as part of the script to `sh`.

Comment: Look at what happens when you run this after `mkdir -p '.evil/rm $(rm -rf ' && touch '.evil/rm $(rm -rf /*).md'`. Or, rather, don't if you value your system.

Comment: Well, if I change the script to the same as @triplee posted, our answers will be the same. Is it worth it? Isn't it better to keep it as is, so others can learn from it? If I would delete it completely, someone else can figure out the same solution as me, but he won't learn about possible issues it can have.

Comment: Great. Thank you for teaching me something I didn't know! BTW I also moved the output redirection out of the script, so it should open a file just once now, shouldn't it?

Comment: Glad to help -- and yes, moving the redirection out fixes that issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll rarely need `find` in `zsh`; its globbing facilities cover nearly every use case of `find`.

```
for f in (#i)**/*.md; do
    cat $f
    print -- "---"
done > all_slides.md
```

This looks in the current directory hierarchy for every file that matches `*.md` in a case-insensitive manner.

For even more efficiency, replace `cat $f` with `< $f`; `zsh` itself will read the file and write its contents to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel cat {}\; print -- --- ::: **/*.md
```